# Electric board clicks and the output VDC is higher than the input AC

Tags: resistors, relay, igbt

I've been working on fixing my treadmill's electric board in the past 2 weeks, and I learned a lot about electronics through this process. But for sorry I can't get it working, yet. I'm providing here all my findings & steps and I'm looking forward for your assistance.

**My treadmill showed me an Err2**. I watched many videos and they all agreed on bad an IBGT (In some videos they changed the biggest capacitor (Cylinder shape) and some resistors). I checked my IGBT and it read (0L).

**I replaced the faulty IGBT**. I tested the new one using the diode mode. But unlike all the videos that says put the positive lead on the Collector (Center leg) and the negative lead on the Emitter to get a reading, in my case it gives 0L. But when I put the positive lead on the Emitter & the negative lead on the Collector, it gives a reading 0.391v. These tests were conducted when the electric board is disconnected from the treadmill cables.

After I replaced the IGBT, I connected the board again to treadmill & turned it on & pressed the start button. But it didn't start nor it showed Err2 (Conditionally, read below).

**But there're a lot of observations**

Notes

- I have 247AC input
- My motor works on 180 VDC, 16 Amp

**1st try and findings**

- I powered up the treadmill
- When I pushed the start button, I heard a click sound (**I watched a video that explained it's because of faulty capacitors which causes the relay to make this clicks & the refrigerator not to start**)
- The motor didn't start and no errors was on the screen.
  **- If I power down the treadmill & start it in a few seconds later, it shows the Err2**
- If I power it down and wait for a few minutes before powering it up, step two takes place.

**2nd try and findings**

- This try takes place if I wait a few minutes after the 1st try
- I detached the motor from the board terminals
- I connected my DMM to the DC terminals in the board
- I powered up the treadmill, the reading took a minute to reach 126VDC (It goes fast at first, and slowly in the last few volts).
- Once I pressed the start button, **I heard a click sound in the board & DMM reading jumped instantly to 260VDC**
- I powered down the treadmill, and the reading gradually went down.

**Capacitors**

All chemical cylinder ones look good, no leaking nor bulging on the top. I didn't detach them for testing (Yet). I accidently touched the biggest capacitors (470 uF 450 WV) with the soldering iron at the top-edge, it removed about a mm of its outer isolation material.

**Rectifier diodes**

Their readings within the normal range of 0.3 : 0.7v using diode test mode.

**Except 2 of them**

The 1st rectifier readings are 0.190v on both sides when I connect (++ -- & +- -+) when connected to the board, and 0.420v (++ --) & 0L (+- -+) when detached from the board.

The 2nd rectifier (Which's directly on the path of the IGBT that I replaced), it read 0.540v when I connect (++ --) & 0.790v when I connect (+- -+) when its connected to the board, but when I detached it, it read 0.540v when connecting (++ --) & 0L on (+- -+).

**GBJ bridge rectified**

Tested it in diode mode and the readings are around 0.425v

**So, where do I go from here?**

Do I go detach resistors, capacitors & relay to test them?

[image]

Comment: I would try to draw the high power circuit path. How can you debug if you don't first come up with what you think should be happening. Is the AC voltage being rectified? If so I would think you should see ~350VDC = (ACV * SQRT(2)). If not seeing that maybe the output is shorted in some way. IGBT can fail short. But I think drawing the circuit is really your first most important step. (even if you get it wrong at least people can help correct that)

Comment: @CarlGilbert Thank you for your assistance, really appreciated. As I mentioned at the beginning of the thread, I'm new to the electronic world. As a software developer I'm aware of the debugging concept & its value. But how can I do that in electronic circuit? That's why I mentioned the symptoms of the problem as detailed as possible. If you can guide me where to learn how to "draw the high power circuit path", that would be really appreciated.

Comment: It's going to be tough if you don't have any background in electronics. You can look at some AC to DC converting circuits online and see if you can find those components on your board.   You sure your motor is a DC motor?

Comment: You won't get around drawing a circuit diagram of your device.